# Do Abstract Factories use "new"?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, abstract-factory

I am trying to use Dependency Injection as much as possible, but I am having trouble when it comes to things like short-lived dependencies.

For example, let's say I have a blog manager object that would like to generate a list of blogs that it found in the database. The options to do this (as far as I can tell) are:

1. new Blog();
2. $this->loader->blog();

   - the loader object creates various other types of objects like database objects, text filters, etc.
3. $this->blogEntryFactory->create();

However, #1 is bad because it creates a strong coupling. #2 still seems bad because it means that the object factory has to be previously injected - exposing all the other objects that it can create.

Number 3 seems okay, but if I use #3, do I put the "new" keywords in the blogEntryFactory itself, OR, do I inject the loader into the blogEntryFactory and use the loader?

If I have many different factories like blogEntryFactory (for example I could have userFactory and commentFactory) it would seem like putting the "new" keyword across all these different factories would be creating dependency problems.

I hope this makes sense...

**NOTE**

I have had some answers about how this is unnecessary for this specific blog example, but there are, in fact, cases where you should use the Abstract Factory Pattern, and that is the point I am getting at. Do you use "new" in that case, or do something else?

Comment: If I didn't explain this correctly or thoroughly enough, please let me know, and I'll try to clarify

Comment: I've never seen dependency injection being used on model classes. Unless the `Blog` class encapsulates some business logic (which models rarely do), there's no point trying to reduce coupling to it – there's no behaviour to couple to. (There's just the structure of the entity, but that's not going to change.)

Comment: First, thanks for the comment...so are you saying then that the BlogManager should / could call "new Blog()"?

Comment: If `Blog` is just a "dumb" data structure with no behaviour, and you don't think it will ever have any behaviour, then yes.

Comment: Still though doesn't it seem like there should be a level of abstraction? What if I needed to unit test?

Comment: In what scenario would you need a mock implementation of a model entity *with no behaviour*? You can check the attributes of the real implementation just as well. (Once again, this is assuming that `Blog` doesn't really encapsulate anything as much as bunch some data together.)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In that instance, you make a lot of sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7294/discussion-between-johnnietheblack-and-inerdial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert, but I'm going to take a crack at this.  This assumes that `Blog` is just a data model object that acts as a container for some data and gets filled by the controller (`new Blog` is not very meaningful).  In this case, `Blog` is a leaf of the object graph, and using `new` is okay.  If you are going to test methods that need to create a `Blog`, you have to simultaneously test the creation of the `Blog` anyway, and using a mock object doesn't make sense .. the `Blog` does not persist past this method.

As an example, say that PHP did not have an array construct but had a collections object.  Would you call `$this->collectionsFactory->create()` or would you be satisfied to say `new Array;`?

Comment: Enlightening with the leaf explanation.

Comment: Tandu, as I just added above, though this scenario might not merit a factory, there are scenarios where factories are merited. In those cases, do you use "new" in the Factory, or do something else?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the title: yes, abstract factories typically use `new`. For example, see the `MazeFactory` code on page 92 of the GoF book. It includes, `return new Maze;` `return new Wall;` `return new Room;` `return new Door;`

In answer to the note: a design that uses abstract factories to create data models is highly suspect. The purpose is to vary the behavior of the factory's products while making their concrete implementations invisible to clients. Data models with no behavior do not benefit from an abstract factory.